# docker-compose with wp-cli and custom theme wrong permission

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have the docker-compose file at the end of the post
In this file I create a volume to link the custom theme folder.
When I try to run a wp-cli command  in a **CONTAINER - CLI** I have a permission problem because the folder **wp-content** is owned by root and the container is run as user xfs.
In the **CONTAINER - WORDPRESS** we can see that the wp-content folder is also owned by root.

| CONTAINER - WORDPRESS | CONTAINER - CLI |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

---

But when I unlink my custom theme folders this issue no longer happens.
it is possible to see in the **CONTAINER - CLI** that the owner of the **wp-content** folder is xfs as it is correct, as well as in the **WORDPRESS - CONTAINER** the wp-content folder also belongs to the user www-data as it should be.

| CONTAINER - WORDPRESS | CONTAINER - CLI |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

This is mine **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
    
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:5.2.1-php7.3
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: database:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX}
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: ${WORDPRESS_DEBUG:-false}
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp:/var/www/html # Full wordpress project
      - ./theme:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/custom-theme # Theme development
    ports:
      - ${WORDPRESS_PORT}:80
    depends_on:
      - database
  
  cli:
    image: wordpress:cli-2.3.0
    env_file: .env
    user: xfs
    depends_on:
      - database
      - wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./wp:/var/www/html
    
  database:
    image: mariadb:10.5.9
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u root --password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5

  manage:
    image: phpmyadmin:5
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - ${MANAGE_PORT}:80
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
     
volumes:
  db_data:
  wp_data:
```

Answer (score 0):

I found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60011732/13160199) here on StackOverflow that you need to add `./wp-content/:/var/www/html/wp-content/` to the volumes, because:

> Docker defaults any named volumes to root, so by binding it dropped the root owner.